# Getting file size / type in IE with javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I got a javascript code that works in FF, chrome and other browser except IE

Here it is

```
    var inputfile = document.getElementById('inputfilename');
    var filetype = inputfile.files[0].type;
    var filesize = inputfile.files[0].size;
    var filename = inputfile.files[0].name;
```

Now the variable filetype, filesize  and filename is undefined in IE
So how to get those three property in IE ?
Any help will be appreciated.

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vY9y8/

Comment: why dont you create a jsfiddle and share a link? so that it will be easy to debug.

Comment: Ok I added a jsfiddle thanks man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1: Wait for IE 10 (which should [support the bleeding edge File API spec)](http://caniuse.com/#search=file%20api)

Option 2: Use another technology that can access that sort of information. Possible Flash or a signed Java applet.

Comment: oh so IE cannot get those property within the inputfile html tag ?

Comment: No, it doesn't support File API. Microsoft are quite conservative about implementing new specifications in IE these days.